# Set fieldname in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

Is there a way for directing Entity Framework what to call a field?

In this example, when creating the `Student` table, I want EF to create the `Author` field with the column name of `AuthorId`.

As an example:

```
namespace Student.Models
{
    public class Student: ViewModelBase
    {
        [Key(), Column("StudentId", Order = 10)]
        public int StudentId { get; set; }

        [Column("Description", Order = 20), Display(Name = "Description"),  
         Required(ErrorMessage = "An Name is required.")]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Enter Student Name")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Student Name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        public string Name  { get; set; }

        [Column("AuthorId", Order = 30)]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public virtual User Author { get; set; }
    }

    public class User : ViewModelBase
    {
        [Key(), Column("UserId", Order = 10)]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId  { get; set; }

        [Column("Username", Order = 20), Required(ErrorMessage = "A Username is required.")]
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Enter Username")]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        [StringLength(maximumLength: 20, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Username cannot be longer than 20 characters and must be at least 2 characters.")]
        public string Username   { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a navigation property non an scalar property, in order to have a column you need to declare an scalar property, Why didn't you create it?

Comment: A mistake - thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy in fact, just do something like

```
public class ViewModelBase {
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I tried the suggested update, however the table gets created with two fields:  Author and UserId

Comment: I also tried adding the column modifier to the class:  [ScaffoldColumn(false)]

Comment: EF won't create the virtual field column, only the one of the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ViewModelBase {
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AuthorId))]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }
}
```